# Text color depends of value

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, textblock

First of all, I am new to WPF and Xaml, so I just hope that you understand what I am asking.

I got this situation: There is a listBox of Animals. Every Animal has Weight property. What I am trying to achieve is whenever Weight of Animal is greater then 300 kg, that Weight should be displayed red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use custom converter to achieve that. If your item looks like that:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and ItemTemplate like that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnimalTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Weight, Converter={StaticResource AnimalColorSelector}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your converter will be like the following one:

```
public class AnimalColorSelector : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly Color _overweightColor = Colors.Red;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            return (int) value > 300 ? new SolidColorBrush(_overweightColor) : Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This approach has the following pros:

1. You don't need to hardcode the default color, but inherit it by using `Binding.DoNothing`.
2. You don't need to store any style information in a view model.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ViewModel for Animals that would contain necessary logic for color setting. Like this:

```cs
public class VMAnimal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _weight;
    public int Weight 
    { 
        get { return _weight; }
        set
        {
            _weight = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Weight");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Weight > 300) 
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it with binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Weight}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" />
```